# Error when trying to populate ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-binding

Currently I'm trying to populate ObservableCollection but getting this error
 `is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection`
The Autocompletebox is populated with numbers, and when I try to select an item from the list the error is produced.

May I get some guidances towards where I'm going wrong.

```
public ObservableCollection<int> number = new ObservableCollection<int>();

public ObservableCollection<int> Number
{
    get { return value; }
    set
    {
        number = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Number");
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<PaymentInfo> Payments
    { get; set; }
```

xaml side:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox
    SelectedItems="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}"  
    DisplayMemberPath="PaymentNo"      
    TextSearchPath="PaymentNo" />
```

Comment: `ItemsSource` is bound to `PaymentInfo` items so `SelectedItems` should be of the same type and not `int`

Comment: THANKS BUD.!!!!!!! definitely was the result. I was stuck all day.

Answer (score 0):

Would define the following property

```
    public ObservableCollection<PaymentInfo> SelectedPayments
{
    get { return value; }
    set
    {
        number = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPayments");
    }
}
```

Bind it to  `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPayments, Mode=TwoWay}"`